# wireless pcmcia rtl8085L will not connect after entering Key

Tags: wireless, networking, ubuntu-drivers

Running 12.04 , card is enabled and sees networks and ask for authorization, but will not connect after entering correct passphase, card is Cendyne And I have downloaded correct driver, but the driver that is installed is RTL8080 and I do not know who to update it if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The chip is supported out-of-the-box by Ubuntu. **Unfortunately** WPA isn't possible with this driver.

Therefore you will need to go with the Windows driver of Realtek and use ndiswrapper to get going. Canonical has an official documentation on how to setup Ubuntu to work with a [RTL8180L chip](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/RTL8180L)

Here are the steps to install it copied from the above link:

1. Install following packages: ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.8 ndisgtk wpasupplicant network-manager network-manager-gnome.
2. Find a binary driver for Windows 98 Second Edition on [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=26&PFid=5&Level=6&Conn=5&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true) site and download it.
3. Unpack downloaded zip file to `/opt` (root privileges might be required).
4. Disable open-source driver (it will conflict with closed source). Open `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` file with text editor (eg. with `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`). Then add the following two lines to the end of the list:

   ```
   blacklist r818x
   blacklist ieee80211_rtl
   ```
5. Go to System->Adminsitration->Windows Wireless Drivers and install downloaded driver. More about installing ndiswrapper [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper)
6. Use [Network Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/NetworkManager) to configure access to your WPA protected network.